# Тип MySQL для текста, длинной меньше 20 символов - подскажите

Tags: mysql

Подскажите тип MySQL для текста, длинной меньше 20 символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M - от 1 до 255

CHAR(M)
       Строка, всегда имеющая длину M ( если занесённое значение короче,
       оно дополняется пробелами).

VARCHAR(M)
       Аналогично CHAR, за исключением  того, что длина значения может быть
       произвольной (от 1 до M ), а все пробелы в конце строки удаляются.

TINYTEXT
       Тип TEXT, длиной от 1 до 255 символов.
```

[Отсюда](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/mysql_types.txt.html)